# No puedo instalar pillow in python 312-32

Tags: python, python-3.x, pillow

estoy intentando instalar algunas librerías en la version de python 3.12 de 32bits en mi pc. Pero me empezaba a aparecer un error por pillow. Intenté instalar pillow mediante el siguiente comando:

```
py -m pip install pillow
```

tambien intenté `py -m pip install pillow --no-cache`

Consulte a la IA pero me daba la misma solucion, e incluso intenté una solucion que ví en [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Yah7YHi9qc&pp=ygUmcHl0aG9uIGVycm9yIGJ1aWxkaW5nIHdoZWVsIGZvciBwaWxsb3c%3D) que es basicamente instalar una versión anterior, pero nada funciona. Siempre me da el mismo error:

```
C:\Users\PC>py -m pip install pillow==7.2.0
Collecting pillow==7.2.0
  Downloading Pillow-7.2.0.tar.gz (39.1 MB)
     ---------------------------------------- 39.1/39.1 MB 1.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: pillow
  Building wheel for pillow (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for pillow (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [195 lines of output]
      <string>:42: RuntimeWarning: Pillow 7.2.0 does not support Python 3.12 and does not provide prebuilt Windows binaries. We do not recommend building from source on Windows.
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win32-cpython-312
      creating build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\BdfFontFile.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\BlpImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\BmpImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\BufrStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ContainerIO.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\CurImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\DcxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\DdsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\EpsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ExifTags.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\features.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\FitsStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\FliImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\FontFile.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\FpxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\FtexImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\GbrImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\GdImageFile.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\GifImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\GimpGradientFile.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\GimpPaletteFile.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\GribStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\Hdf5StubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\IcnsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\IcoImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\Image.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageChops.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageCms.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageColor.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageDraw.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageDraw2.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageEnhance.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageFile.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageFilter.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageFont.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageGrab.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageMath.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageMode.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageMorph.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageOps.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImagePalette.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImagePath.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageQt.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageSequence.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageShow.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageStat.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageTk.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageTransform.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageWin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImtImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\IptcImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\Jpeg2KImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\JpegImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\JpegPresets.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\McIdasImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\MicImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\MpegImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\MpoImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\MspImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\PaletteFile.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\PalmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\PcdImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\PcfFontFile.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\PcxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\PdfImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\PdfParser.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\PixarImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\PngImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\PpmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\PsdImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\PSDraw.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\PyAccess.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\SgiImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\SpiderImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\SunImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\TarIO.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\TgaImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\TiffImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\TiffTags.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\WalImageFile.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\WebPImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\WmfImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\XbmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\XpmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\XVThumbImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\_binary.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\_tkinter_finder.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\_util.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\_version.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\__main__.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\PIL
      running egg_info
      writing src\Pillow.egg-info\PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to src\Pillow.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
      writing top-level names to src\Pillow.egg-info\top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'src\Pillow.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      warning: no files found matching '*.c'
      warning: no files found matching '*.h'
      warning: no files found matching '*.sh'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching '.appveyor.yml'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching '.editorconfig'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching '.readthedocs.yml'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching 'codecov.yml'
      warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
      no previously-included directories found matching '.ci'
      adding license file 'LICENSE'
      writing manifest file 'src\Pillow.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      running build_ext


      The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
      a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.

      Please see the install instructions at:
         https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 864, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-f_63bb_p\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 103, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-f_63bb_p\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 185, in setup
          return run_commands(dist)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-f_63bb_p\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 201, in run_commands
          dist.run_commands()
        File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-f_63bb_p\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 969, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-f_63bb_p\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 963, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-f_63bb_p\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-f_63bb_p\overlay\Lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 368, in run
          self.run_command("build")
        File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-f_63bb_p\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 318, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-f_63bb_p\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 963, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-f_63bb_p\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-f_63bb_p\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build.py", line 131, in run
          self.run_command(cmd_name)
        File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-f_63bb_p\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 318, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-f_63bb_p\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 963, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-f_63bb_p\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-f_63bb_p\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 345, in run
          self.build_extensions()
        File "<string>", line 694, in build_extensions
      RequiredDependencyException: zlib

      During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312-32\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312-32\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312-32\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 251, in build_wheel
          return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-f_63bb_p\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 404, in build_wheel
          return self._build_with_temp_dir(
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-f_63bb_p\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 389, in _build_with_temp_dir
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-f_63bb_p\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 480, in run_setup
          super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend, self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
        File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-f_63bb_p\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 311, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 918, in <module>
      RequiredDependencyException:

      The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
      a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.

      Please see the install instructions at:
         https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html


      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pillow
Failed to build pillow
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pillow, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

No se si esto pasa porque es la versión de 32bits de python. Por favor, si alguien sabe cómo ayudarme, gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pillow no proporciona wheels precompilados para 32 bits desde la versión 10. Al no disponer del paquete precompilado, `pip` intenta compilarlo y construirlo desde la fuentes, el problema es que no tienes las dependencias necesarias para ello.

Supongo que tienes una buena razón para usar la versión de 32 bits del interprete, por lo que pasarse a Python 64-bits lo descarto. Por lo tanto tus opciones son:

- Instalar una versión anterior a Pillow 10, **si no tienes algún otro paquete en tu proyecto que requiera de Pillow >= 10** seria la opción mas simple:

  ```
  py -m pip install "pillow < 10.0"
  ```

  En tu caso falla porque estas forzando la instalación de de pillow 7.2, el cual no tiene precompilados para Python 3.12 (Python 3.8 es la mayor versión para la que los provee). Al no disponer de la versión para tu interprete vuelve a intentar construir desde las fuentes igual que pasa con pillow 10. [No deberías tener problemas con la versión 9.5](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/9.5.0/#files).
- Instalar desde las fuentes como intentas ahora, pero instalando las dependencias necesarias primero. No es sencillo, especialmente en  Windows...

  Pillow necesita obligatoriamente `Zlib` (que es la dependencia que causa que tu compilación falle) y `libjpeg`. Ademas existen un montón mas de dependencias opcionales dependiendo de para que y que archivos pretendas manejar con pillow. Tienes una lista completa en la documentación oficial:

  [Pillow-Installation-Building_from_source](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html#building-from-source)

  En la propia documentación te recomiendan usar los scripts para construir desde las fuentes que proporcionan en el [directorio *winbuild* del repositorio de GitHub](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/tree/main/winbuild) en el caso de Windows. Dicho script requiere de Visual Studio 2017 o mas reciente y [NASM](https://nasm.us/). Tienes instrucciones detalladas del proceso en su repo de GitHub:

  https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/main/winbuild/build.rst

Comment: Hola @FJSevilla muchas gracias por tu ayuda (Vengo contestando ahorita porque cambié de pc recientemente). Al final instalé la versión 9.6 y funcionó. Y si, tengo una muy buena razón para usar la arquitectura de 32bits, el software que programé para mi empleador actual tiene muchos clientes con PCs del 2010 con windows viejísimos de 32bits. Tengo que migrar todo el código de python a 32 bits para que funciones. Al final no se si va a ser posible, pero espero que si...